# Rotate UIButton on change of orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uideviceorientation

I have round button which consists of the following image

[image]

Now on rotation of device I want to rotate the button in a way that the image maintains the orientation.

How can I achieve this,

I do not want to change the frame of the button i want it to stay where it is I just want to transform the button.

Comment: Have you tried changing image on orientation ?

Comment: I do not want to do that I do not want to keep four different images for different orientation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an IBOutlet Object.

```
theButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -4);
```

If you want to create run time button on view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 44)];
  btn.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -4);
  [btn setTitle:@"RakeshBhatt" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.view addSubview:btn];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To rotate a image view try this

```
// Set the anchor point and center so the view swings from the upper right
imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);
imageView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 0.0);

// Rotate 90 degrees to hide it off screen
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DegreesToRadians(90));
swingView.transform = rotationTransform;
```

Comment: I am sorry I do not have an UIImageView I have a UIButton with image!